# Clicking text to select a checkbox

Tags: checkbox

I noticed that on certain websites, if you want to tick a checkbox on or off, you just need to click the corresponding text. When I put a checkbox with some descriptive text on my page, I have to actually hit the checkbox for it to get ticked. How is the former effect achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a `<label>` as in this example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="call" id="willcall">
<label for="willcall">click on this text to select the checkbox</label>
```

This example from: http://www.askdavetaylor.com/make_text_adjacent_to_checkbox_clickable.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that they use a JS script to achieve this. It's most likely a label that is being clicked, and they might add an onclick() event to the label which uses the javascript to find the checkbox and add the CHECKED attribute to it. Sorry for not supplying code, but I hope that gives you some understanding on what those websites do.